# Why str is not converting object into string in python?

Tags: python

Content of /home/user/reverse.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/environment python2.7

def reverse(string):
    print("reversed: "+string[::-1])

name=str(input("Key in String to Reverse:"))
reverse(name)

$python /home/user/reverse.py
Key in String to Reverse:abcdef
```

While executing error:

```
name abcdef is not defined.
```

Plese help me in resolving the issue!

Comment: Use `raw_input` to read from user.

Comment: In python 2 you need to use `raw_input` instead of `input` but you really should just use python 3

Comment: its there at the top, 2.7

Comment: If you are new to Python, you have no need to use Python 2, which is at end-of-life.  The majority of Python users had switched to Py3 as of about five years ago.